# Bijection between sets and complements

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Suppose $f: A\rightarrow B$ is a bijection. For $A,B \subseteq C$. Show that a bijective map $h: C\setminus A \rightarrow C\setminus B$ exists.

I'm not sure how to proceed, may I have a hint please?

Comment: Do you mean $h \colon C \setminus A \to C \setminus B$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes

Comment: So what if $A$ is the even integers, and $B$ and $C$ are all integers?  The sets $A$ and $B$ are bijective, but $C\setminus A$ is infinite while $C \setminus B$ is empty.

Comment: If a bijection exists between $A$ and $B$ the $|A| = |B|$ so it would suffice to show that $|A|=|B| \implies |C\setminus A| = |C\setminus B|$.  But that is false in general.However it is true for finite $C$.  Or for any $|A| < |C|$.  But if $|C|=|A|$ and $C$ infinite... it's not true.  Matthew Leingang's comment is a perfect counter example.

Comment: does it in the end imply, that we can prove that the initial statement is false by contradiction, since atleast one circumstand doesnt allow the statements condition?

Comment: Yes, “true” means true in all interpretations; any single counterexample renders the entire statement false.  If this is an assigned problem, perhaps you're missing some additional hypothesis?  Or misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang No, it is something I conjectured.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments I think the question has been answered collectively by fleablood, CoffeeArabica, and me.

**If $C$ is finite, the conjecture is true.** To show that a bijection exists between $C \setminus A$ and $C \setminus B$, it suffices to show the sets have the same cardinality.  Since $A$ and $B$ are bijective, $|A| = |B|$.  Therefore
$$
    \left|C \setminus A\right| = |C| - |A| = |C| - |B| = \left|C \setminus B\right|
$$

**If $C$ is infinite, the conjecture is false.**  For a counterexample, let $A = 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=C=\mathbb{Z}$.  Let $f \colon A \to B$ be the map $x \mapsto \frac{1}{2}x$, a bijection.    Then $C \setminus A$ is the set of odd integers (which is infinite), and $C \setminus B$ is the empty set.  Therefore a bijection between these complements is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $C$ to be a finite set:

To be a bijection $|A|=|B|$ and since $ A,B \subseteq C \Longrightarrow |C|-|A|=|C_1|=|C|-|B|=|C_2|$

$|C\setminus A| = |C_1| = |C_2| = |C\setminus B|$

So there is indeed the option to map $h: C\setminus A \longrightarrow C\setminus B$ 
, and the option $h^{-1}:C\setminus B \longrightarrow C\setminus A$

Comment: It seems you have overlooked the counterexample in the comments...

Comment: But doesnt it hold when C is finite?

Comment: That's better with the condition on $C$...

Comment: "It seems you have overlooked the counterexample in the comments... "  No s/he didn't.  The counterexample shows that this can only be true if $C$ is finite.  For finite sets $A \subset C$ we have $|C\setminus A| = |C| -|A|$ (this is *not* true for infinite sets but *is* true and easily proven for finite sets.) With this condition this result is completely valid.

Comment: Oh... going through the edit history I see what the comment refers to.